# (Python) Importing data from text file into object

Tags: python

I have this code

```
class List(object):
  def __init__(self, name=None, age=None, license=None):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.license=license
peter = List('Peter Peter', '50', 'yes')
martin = List('martin martin','40','no')
```

but I would like to insert my data from a textfile (import more people with their name, age, license). How could I do that? Also, is there any way to make my code better? I am trying to achieve the same results as record function in Pascal. Thanks

Comment: Please correctly indent your code.

Comment: You can use a csv file. Look up the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Using `import csv`, you can fetch the data from the csv file into arrays which can be passed into your class.

Comment: what is "record function"? Your code, as written, looks fine to me. That being said, if these are meant to be record types, i.e., containers for ordered data, consider using a `namedtuple`. As for the text file, you are going to have to elaborate on the format. My suggestion would be to use a standard text-serialization format, i.e. JSON or csv, so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Record

Comment: @Johny547 ah, so you probably want a list of named-tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas package to import a CSV file. For more details refer the 
[link](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv/)

To read a CSV file you can use:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.txt', index_col=False, header=0);
```

You can access the value from the df using:

```
df["column_name"]
```